# Stripe CLI: How do you pass an empty array?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a Stripe billing portal configuration using the CLI: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configurations/create?lang=cli

For this particular configuration I want to block updates to the subscription, ie I'm passing `-d "features[subscription_update][enabled]"=false`

But under subscription update there are some other required fields: `features.subscription_update.default_allowed_updates` is an array of enums, and `features.subscription_update.products` is an array of nested objects.

As I want to disable the feature, I'd like to set both of these arrays to empty: no update types are allowed, and no products can be updated. But I can't figure out how to do this.

I've tried:

- Excluding the fields from my request. I get an error saying they're required (as documented)
- Passing an emtpy string eg. `-d "features[subscription_update][default_allowed_updates][]"=`. I get an error indicating that this is not allowed:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_invalid_empty",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-empty",
    "message": "You passed an empty string for 'features[subscription_update][default_allowed_updates][0]'. We assume empty values are an attempt to unset a parameter; however 'features[subscription_update][default_allowed_updates][0]' cannot be unset. You should remove 'features[subscription_update][default_allowed_updates][0]' from your request or supply a non-empty value.",
    "param": "features[subscription_update][default_allowed_updates][0]",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

- Passing an empty array explicitly: `-d "features[subscription_update][default_allowed_updates]"="[]"`. I get an error indicating that this is invalid:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid array",
    "param": "features[subscription_update][products]",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me with how I can correctly pass an empty array for these fields please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd send this by sending the empty string, as you tried:

```
-d "features[subscription_update][enabled]=false" 
-d "features[subscription_update][default_allowed_updates]="
-d "features[subscription_update][products]="
```

The reason it didn't work for you is that you were trying to set the first entry to an empty string, rather than the list itself.